# How to extract data from three tables with date manipulation

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, join

I have three tables as shown in below images. What I want to do is,

- list Parties whose last RecoveryDate was 30 days old.
- list Parties whose last RecoveryDate was 60 days old.
- list Parties whose last RecoveryDate was 90 days old.

I'm using PHP 7.4 running on XAMPP and SQL Server 2008 R2 but I want to implement it through purely SQL way.

Here's the tables schema (rough)

```
dbo.Parties
PartyID
PartyName

dbo.Recovery
RecoveryID
RecoveryDate


dbo.RecoveryBody
RecoveryID
CustomerID   //PartyID
AmountRecoverd
```

I want something like this (along with 30, 60, 90 days interval). I'm not getting the desired result though as its giving me multiple instances of ***PartyName***, where as I want one instance of ***PartyName*** only with last ***RecoveryDate*** and ***AmountRecovered***.

```
SELECT Parties.PartyName, CAST(RecoveryDate AS date) AS RecoveryDate, AmountRecoverd 
FROM RecoveryBody
LEFT JOIN Recovery ON RecoveryBody.RecoveryID = Recovery.RecoveryID
LEFT JOIN Parties ON Parties.PartyID = RecoveryBody.CustomerID
GROUP BY PartyName, RecoveryDate, AmountRecoverd
ORDER BY RecoveryDate DESC
```

Comment: On SO please avoid using images and instead add data as formatted text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try something like below. Not sure about the result since I don't have data to test. But you can achieve the desired result by using <kbd>[CTE](https://www.essentialsql.com/introduction-common-table-expressions-ctes/)</kbd>

```
WITH CTE AS(
SELECT distinct Parties.PartyID,
       Parties.PartyName, 
       CAST(RecoveryDate AS date) AS RecoveryDate, 
       AmountRecoverd,
       ROW_NUMBER()over (partition by Parties.PartyID ORDER BY RecoveryDate  DESC) RN
FROM RecoveryBody
LEFT JOIN Recovery ON RecoveryBody.RecoveryID = Recovery.RecoveryID
LEFT JOIN Parties ON Parties.PartyID = RecoveryBody.CustomerID)
SELECT * 
FROM CTE 
WHERE RN=1
```

Comment: So, in order to understand the concept, you used 'RN=1' clause to display the first row of every batch of PartyID, right?

Comment: Yes...You can remove DISTINCT as well..this is unnecessary in your case. Is it giving desire result?

Comment: Yes, it did work. Great. I'm however trying to apply the filter for 60 days barrier. I'm using ```WHERE RecoveryDate NOT BETWEEN  '2/3/2020' AND '11/1/2019'``` after the JOINs but its not filtering at all.

Comment: Ok. I've completed the query. I put ```AND RecoveryDate < DATEADD(day, -90, GETDATE())``` after ```WHERE RN=1``` instead of using it after the ```JOINs```. This gives me the desired output. This way, the clause is applied to final result.